# How can I create a nested array with specific data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
"devices": [    
        {   
            "id": 26090,    
            "name": "MP28L1136",    
            "latitude": 22.053656,  
            "longitude": 78.938591, 
            "angle": 0, 
            "speed": 0, 
            "ignition": 0,  
            "device_time": "2019-12-05 03:18:15",   
            "server_time": "2019-12-05 04:57:56"    
        },  
        {   
            "id": 26091,    
            "name": "MP28L.1206.w14",   
            "latitude": 22.065143,  
            "longitude": 78.949202, 
            "angle": 330,   
            "speed": 0, 
            "ignition": 1,  
            "device_time": "2019-12-05 05:00:28",   
            "server_time": "2019-12-05 05:00:31"    
        }
    ]
```

I have response from API like the above. Though there are so many records in the api but I have shown only few records for example. I want to create an array with the help of this like following-

```
positions = [[22.053656, 78.938591], [22.065143, 78.949202], [22.065748, 78.951584]]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: `[22.065748, 78.951584]` Where is this from?

Comment: You can use `map` to loop through the array.

Comment: array map will do the trick

Comment: There are so many records in API, Almost 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach would be,

```
let resArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i<devices.length; i++){
  let arr = [devices[i].latitude, devices[i].longitude];
  resArr.push(arr);
}
console.log(resArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through them:

```js
const devices = [
  {   
    "id": 26090,    
    "name": "MP28L1136",    
    "latitude": 22.053656,  
    "longitude": 78.938591, 
    "angle": 0, 
    "speed": 0, 
    "ignition": 0,  
    "device_time": "2019-12-05 03:18:15",   
    "server_time": "2019-12-05 04:57:56"    
  },  
  {   
    "id": 26091,    
    "name": "MP28L.1206.w14",   
    "latitude": 22.065143,  
    "longitude": 78.949202, 
    "angle": 330,   
    "speed": 0, 
    "ignition": 1,  
    "device_time": "2019-12-05 05:00:28",   
    "server_time": "2019-12-05 05:00:31"    
  }
]

const result = devices.map(device => [device.latitude, device.longitude])

console.log(result)
```